# How to make backup Raspbian image?

Tags: raspbian, image, backup

I'm using latest version of Raspbian from http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest

I've made changes to this image, can an image copy be taken which includes all OS changes made to Raspbian and copied to another MicroSD card ? So if current one fails I use card used to make copy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an image backup using [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) or other similar software like it.

If you want to make a backup image of an operational system, I would advise you to use `dd`. An important thing to consider here is to shut down all running processes before you make the backup using `dd` so as to make sure nothing is being written/read from the SD card. Common processes to shut down would be Apache/Nginx, MySQL server and others like it.

I personally use the following command to run a backup of the SD card every night using cron and copy it to a mounted External HDD

`sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4096 | pv -s 7761M | sudo dd bs=4096 of=/media/NASDRIVE/backup.img`

In the above code, `/dev/mmcblk0` is the SD card and `/media/NASDRIVE/backup.img` is the External HDD path to which `dd` writes the backup image. You may omit the `pv -s 7761M` part of the code but it shows a nice progress bar while backup is running.

Answer (score 0):

I use `dd` on my Mac:

```
sudo dd if='/dev/rdisk<disk number>' of='image.dmg'
```

`rdisk` is quicker than `disk`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no OS information available for the computer which you are going to back up the SD Card, I can suggest to have a look on:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

If you are a MAC user, [Apple Pi Baker](http://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/raspberry-pi/macosx-apple-pi-baker/) might help you as well.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the discussion.  Answers that primarily link to other resources are usually discouraged since the link can die.  Please expand your answer.

Comment: This is a link from official Raspberry Pi Web page. And the second link is to a tool. Actually I do not find copy-paste from another page very honest. I will delete my response if I can, instead of repeating the official source.

Comment: It doesn't have to be stolen.  Generally, a summary of the content and a link is the preferred course of action in this case.